# Help with writing MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

With the following tables:

`Party.(PartyId, PartyTypeCode)` and `Member.(MemberId (FK), Name)`

I want to fill in the MemberId column with the value of the PartyId after a new Party is created.

I know the SQL below is wrong but that is why I am looking for help in making it right.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_member_create AFTER INSERT on Party
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.PartyTypeCode = 'M' THEN
        INSERT Member(MemberId)
        VALUES('Party.PartyId')
    END IF;
END;
```

Thanks to Nanne's input this is what works:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER tgr_member_create AFTER INSERT on Party
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.PartyTypeCode = 'M' THEN
        INSERT Member (MemberId,Name)
        VALUES(NEW.PartyId, 'someName');
    END IF;
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values should call the `NEW` row, just as you do with the partytypecode I guess? I'm assuming

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER tgr_member_create AFTER INSERT on Party
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.PartyTypeCode = 'M' THEN
        INSERT Member (MemberId,Name)
        VALUES(NEW.PartyId, 'someName')
    END IF;
END;$$
```

Pay attention to the delimiter code. Because you are using `;` inside, you can't use it as a normal 'end-of-command' token. that's why the `&&`

For debugging:
Make sure the query works when you perform it outside a trigger:

```
INSERT Member (MemberId,Name)
VALUES(party-id goes here, 'someName')
```

There could be a small mistake there. Fill in your partyId obviously.

Comment: thanks.  I still get an error when I try to add this to the db.  "This will not fill the 'name' field of the member table ofcourse :)"  could this be part of the problem since Name is a required field?  Do I need to add that to the trigger also?  The error is generic "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 6 "

Comment: Well, the sql you do in your trigger must be valid. So if  name is required, you should add it. The error is something elseL are you doing everything allright with delimiters? I'll add a more complete example

Comment: thanks for you help.  I took your code and added DELIMITER ; to overcome the ; inside as I had.  Now that I have this though I think I might be going about things in the wrong way.  Maybe I need a stored procedure rather then a trigger since I will be getting my Name from a PHP form?

Comment: There are -as far as i'm concerned - only a couple of valid uses of triggers. For instance to keep data integrity, logging certain actions etc. Most work could better be handled in somthing like a procedure, or a piece of code with  a transaction indeed. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_member_create AFTER INSERT on Party
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.PartyTypeCode = 'M' THEN
        INSERT Member(MemberId)
        VALUES('New.PartyId')
    END IF;
END;
```